placing multiple pyspark dataframe files in azure container from databricks
Is there a way to put multiple files in Pyspark dataframes to azure explorer container in one code ?
lets say i have following pyspark dataframes generated in my code.
df1= pyspark.sql("select * from ABC")
df2= pyspark.sql("select * from XYZ")
df3= pyspark.sql("select * from PQR")

would like to put these files from databricks to azure container in a specific folder.
I know using the below code we can place a file.
df1.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').save("FileStore/xyz/df_cleaned")

The above code will only place one file in df_cleaned folder. However would like to put all the files in df_cleaned (df1,df2,df3). Kindly suggest a suitable way to put all the files in the specific colder (df_cleaned).

As you mentioned you want to create dataframes and move them to storage account to a specific folder
I have tried the below approach:
csv_file_path = "abfss://folder02@dieepstggen2.dfs.core.windows.net/df_cleaned/"
df1.write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(csv_file_path + "df1")
df2.write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(csv_file_path + "df2")
df3.write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(csv_file_path + "df3")

Results:

To write each DataFrame to a different subfolder within the df_cleaned folder using coalesce(1) to have a single CSV file
df1.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(csv_file_path + "df1")
df2.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(csv_file_path + "df2")
df3.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").save(csv_file_path + "df3")

In the above code I have defined the base path for container and the specified folder,using a trailing slash
Next,writing each DataFrame to a different subfolder within the df_cleaned folder
